# setMovementMethod на Android version 4.2 4.3

Tags: android, select, textview, link

Для определения ссылок в `TextView` использую

```
setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

но заметил, на устройствах с Android 4.2 и 4.3 при использовании этой функции перестает работать выделение текста.

Атрибут у `TextView` стоит `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Кто знает чем заменить `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` чтобы на 4.2 и 4.3 работало выделение текста или как реализовать свою реализацию выделения текста для копирования????